# Fortify Command Injection fix

Tags: c#, xml, fortify

Fortify show me a Command Injection on the below code

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    TextReader read = new StringReader(s);

    System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = System.Xml.DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
    settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 100;
    System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Create(read, settings);
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //bad code
```

shows the vulnerability in the following line

```
return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //bad code
```

How can I resolve this situation ?

Note : it doesn't give any error it says this line of code is suspicious

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: it doesn't give any error it says this line of code is suspicious

Comment: https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.configuration.java.dynamic_code_evaluation_unsafe_deserialization

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940056/14419

Answer (score 2):

This is a code *style* warning. There is no *type* checking or error handling around that line of code, most linters would pick up *explicit* casts as warnings by default because it is *suspicious*.

In your business process you might have justified reason to assume that the type will always cast to `T` or you might fully expect to catch the exception higer up, but in general explicit casts that are not wrapped with exception handling or challenged by type checking are indicators of lazy programming where you are brute forcing a conversion.

It is up to you how to proceed of course, but be aware of the risk that this line of code will result in a runtime error.

[V580. Suspicious explicit type casting. Consider inspecting the expression.](https://pvs-studio.com/en/docs/warnings/v580/)